# Local variables referred from inner class must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, inner-classes, final

Please have a look at the below code

```
private void displayInitialRevenue_Method() {
    //Get the dates from the combo
    String selectedCouple = revenueYearCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (selectedCouple.equals("Select Year")) {
        return;
    }
    String[] split = selectedCouple.split("/");
    //Related to DB
    double totalAmount = 0.0;
    //Get data from the database
    dbConnector = new DBHandler();
    dbConnector.makeConnection();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) initialRevenueTable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    ResultSet selectAllDetails = dbConnector.selectAllDetails("SQL CODE ");
    try {
        if (selectAllDetails.isBeforeFirst() == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This table is empty");
        } else {
            while (selectAllDetails.next()) {
                String clientName = selectAllDetails.getString("Client Name");
                String providerName = selectAllDetails.getString("Provider Name");
                Double amountInvested = selectAllDetails.getDouble("Invest_Amount");
                //Update the table
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Object[] row = {clientName, providerName, amountInvested};
                        model.addRow(row);
                    }
                });
                //Get the total
                totalAmount = totalAmount + amountInvested;
            }
            //Add the sum
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Object[] blankRow = {null};
                    model.addRow(blankRow);
                    Object[] row = {totalAmount};
                    model.addRow(row);

                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sql.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

This entire method is running inside another thread. The UI updates are running inside `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater()`. However pls put attention to the below.

```
Object[]row = {totalAmount};
model.addRow(row);
```

The variable `totalAmount` is not final and it cannot be final because it need to be calculated in the above `while loop`. Since it is not `final` I am unable to use it inside the `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater()` as the error says `Local variables referred  from inner class must be final or effectively final`

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but make an extra variable that IS final and copy the final result of totalAmount into it?

Comment: or create a custom class implementing `Runnable` and pass `totalAmount` to it by its constructor

Comment: @Erik: Thanks, did as you said. It worked.

Comment: @mKorbel: Thanks, followed your advice on tha, except `setValueAt`

Comment: @Erik: Please post your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make an additional variable that *is* Final and then copy the final result of the calculation into it.

```
while (selectAllDetails.next()) {
            String clientName = selectAllDetails.getString("Client Name");
            String providerName = selectAllDetails.getString("Provider Name");
            Double amountInvested = selectAllDetails.getDouble("Invest_Amount");
            //Update the table
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Object[] row = {clientName, providerName, amountInvested};
                    model.addRow(row);
                }
            });
            //Get the total
            totalAmount = totalAmount + amountInvested;
        }
final Double totalAmountInvested = totalAmount; // and now use this one in the Inner
```