# Error: local variable referenced from inner class must be final or effective final

Tags: java, swing

```
JButton[] button = new JButton[noOfDays];

for(int j=0 ;j<studentNameList.size() ;j++) {
    for(int i=0 ;i<button.length ;i++) {
        button[i]=new JButton((i+1)+"");
        attendencepanels.add(button[i]);

        button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ---->  button[i].setBackground(Color.red); //Local variable refenced from inner class must be final or effective final

                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
                }
            });
```

How i can resolve this problem in button[i] within actionPerformed method

Comment: Make the button Array final

Comment: `final JButton[] button = new JButton[noOfDays];`

Comment: either make it global to class or final as suggested by @jens

Comment: And hint: do some prior research the next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner class and local variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338708/inner-class-and-local-variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local variables refered from inner class must be final or effectively final](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165006/local-variables-refered-from-inner-class-must-be-final-or-effectively-final)

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not sure about it, you may be able to obtain the `JButton` reference from the `ActionEvent e` argument. It seems that's what `getSource()` returns (`The object on which the Event initially occurred`) :

Instead of

```
button[i].setBackground(Color.red);
```

try

```
JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
button.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable i gets modified in this context, so the compiler cannot cope with it. Give it a non-changing reference instead:

```
    for(int j=0 ;j<studentNameList.size() ;j++) {
        for(int i=0 ;i<button.length ;i++) {
            JButton btn = new JButton((i+1)+""); // effectively final in that scope
            button[i] = btn;
            attendencepanels.add(btn);
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    btn.setBackground(Color.red); //works now
                }
            });
        }
    }
```